# ActiveRecord: Transform scope to arel node, with strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this scope:

```
scope :finished, -> { where(status: "finished") }
```

I found that that transform a scope into an arel node is just calling #arel on it. All this because I have a complex query, and I want to reuse the conditions:

```
table.join(.....).where(table[:id].eq(2)).where(ThatClass.finished.arel).to_sql
#=> .... AND "that_classes"."status" = $1 ......
```

Why is 'finished' not there? How can I integrate it? This only happens with strings, as if it were an integer or a not null scope, it would print exactly as expected

Comment: Is that the full output? `$1` means the argument is tokenised, it should be on the end of the statement.

Comment: All scope conditions using strings are tokenized internally. I want exactly the token-replaced version, but this doesn't seem to be provided by AR.